# Flex: adding 1 day to a specific date

Tags: apache-flex, date

how can i set a date adding 1 day in flex??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't Flex based on ECMA (basically javascript), if so, try just adding 86400000 milliseconds to the date object? Something like:

```
var mili = 1000;
var secs = 60;
var mins = 60;
var hours = 24;
var day = hours * mins * secs * mili;
var tomorrow = new Date();
var tomorrow.setTime(tomorrow.getTime() + day);
```

Comment: nice.. this works.. 
but this also work

tommorow.date = tommorow.date +1

it automatically change the year and month if it reaches the end of each month

Comment: That is nice. Would adding 24 hours to a date not do that?

Answer (score 3):

tommorow date arithmetic suggested by @Treby can be uses this way by using Date(year, month, day) constructor :

```
var now:Date = Date(); 
var currentDate = now.date; 
var currentMonth = now.month; 
var currentYear = now.fullYear; 


var tomorrow:Date = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate + 1);  
var lastWeek:Date = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate  - 7); 
var lastMonth:Date = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth-1, currentDate);
```

etc.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
var date:Date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
```

As this considers the summer timechange days, when days have 23h or 25h.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I took this helper function from [this blog post](http://flexoop.com/2008/12/flex-dateutils-dateadd/), but it's just a snippet.

The usage is simple:

```
 dateAdd("date", +2); //now plus 2 days
```

then

```
static public function dateAdd(datepart:String = "", number:Number = 0, date:Date = null):Date
{
    if (date == null) {
        date = new Date();
    }

    var returnDate:Date = new Date(date.time);;

    switch (datepart.toLowerCase()) {
        case "fullyear":
        case "month":
        case "date":
        case "hours":
        case "minutes":
        case "seconds":
        case "milliseconds":
            returnDate[datepart] += number;
            break;
        default:
            /* Unknown date part, do nothing. */
            break;
    }
    return returnDate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

or if you are after a fancy solution you can use the library Flex Date Utils http://flexdateutils.riaforge.org/, which has a lot of useful operations

best